# Windows phone 8.1 app crashing after first launch when accessing local settings (UnauthorizedException)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

My project is almost ready now. To check if the app is launched for the first time, I am accessing the local folder of the application in the `App.OnLaunched()` function and setting a new value if it is null. The code inside the conditional statement seems to execute properly as the app works fine on the subsequent runs. Can anyone help to workaround this problem and see if the app can be run for the first time without crashing?

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
#if DEBUG
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
    }
#endif


    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    var localSettings  = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    if (localSettings.Values["waslaunched"]==null)
    {
        //Code for first launch
        localSettings.Values["waslaunched"] = "launched";
    }

    //Other autogenerated code in OnLaunched()
}
```

Debugger shows the following exception
System.UnauthorizedException: Access Is Denied

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking null try below code

```
 Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        if (!localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("waslaunched"))
        {
           localSettings.Values.Add("waslaunched", "launched");
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP here. Unfortunately, even your solution seems to run into the exact same problem. The app starts and crashes and then functions properly in the second and subsequent runs

Comment: Can you post exception details?

Comment: The debugger is showing System.UnauthorizedException: Access Is Denied